# Is there a word that conveys an extreme distaste to the point nearing phobia?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm a strong swimmer, and I enjoy recreational lap swimming in pools.  I enjoy sitting by an outdoor pool on vacation, and swimming to cool off.

But, I detest swimming in natural water (lakes, rivers, oceans, etc.). I will go out of my way to avoid it.

I'm not afraid of doing so. I've never had a traumatic experience. My parents didn't drown. I'm not afraid to go over bridges. I've enjoyed sailing and motor boating.  I've even swam in the ocean, lakes, and other bodies of water without incident.

My distaste for it is more based upon the feeling I get while in the water.   It is not at all a panicky feeling. It is not fear. I just feel unpleasantly dirty and disgusted. I dislike the feel of stepping on seaweed or mossy bottoms. I hate sand, and particularly wet sand.

Is there a word to describe this level of irrational hatred for something?  People always think I'm describing a phobia, but as I've said it's not fear based. I want a word to describe my utter revulsion that carries the same gestalt as phobia but, distaste rather than fear based.

Comment: ..........sissy

Comment: Phobia.  If the shoe fits, well.

Comment: @Oldcat It doesn't, though.  I'm not afraid.

Comment: I think you are just exaggerating what those suffering from phobias feel. An arachnophobe doesn't necessarily flee screaming from a spider or a picture of one. They might just feel unpleasant and dirty and disgusted when forced to contact one, and avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: @oldcat Per the DSM-IV, I wouldn't qualify because I don't experience panic attacks with my trigger. As I've said, I have no dysfunction in the face of it. I can/have swam in natural water, I just detest doing so. Perhaps the DSM-IV is a bit too rigid in their definition, but it's the one I tend to default to in matters of psychology.

Comment: This is not a psychology forum. I am not suggesting that you are insane or need help.  In English, phobia does not mean "must have panic attacks".  You think triskaidecaphobes must shriek at the number 13?

Comment: I might consider this a tactile defensiveness. Not generalized, but to non-chlorinated water, which does, honestly, feel different. I wonder if you would feel the same in a pristine fresh-water lake with a pebble beach.

Comment: @Susan my experience has been that, yes I feel the same.

Comment: *Swimming in fresh or salt water repulses me*, would also fit.

Comment: @Oldcat Shriek, no.  But, it causes them consternation to the point where most buildings and elevators don't have a floor number 13.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Another word I have used in the past was *skeeve*.  I'm sure you know that the English slang word derives from *schifare*.  The meaning in English and Italian both derive the older meaning for schifare, which I'm sure you know from terms like *Schifa Noia* ...  Parlo l'italiano, ma ho imparato por Rosetta Stone.

Comment: No, phobia does definitely **not** fit. The word phobia is increasingly misused today especially in political/ideological contexts (homophobia, xenophobia, islamophobia, etc.) where even just a mild dislike (or even just apathy and lack of outright support) is labeled as "phobia". Phobia means an irrational, uncontrollable fear when if the target of the phobia is not avoided, it causes a panic attack, distress and it's a mental health hazard. (I'm not claiming social phobias don't exist, I'm just claiming that a dislike is not the same as a phobia)

Comment: I know a person with a phobia of horses, and it doesn't mean he just doesn't like (or that he hates) horses, and not even that he is just afraid of being close to a horse. It means he will suffer a panic attack, strong allergic reactions (even if the horse is not physically near) even by just seeing a horse. And by panic attack I mean an uncontrollable, shivering, trembling panic attack.

Comment: @DavidM I did not know that *skeeve* derives from *schifare*, The expression: "mi fa schifo" is one I have always liked, it's very flexible meaning *it gives me disgust, contempt, repulsion, etc.* It's a very earthy, and succinct expression. On the other hand, *skeeved me out", I've rarely heard. Maybe it's grown in popularity recently, or it's more common in AmEng than in the UK.

Comment: Perhaps @DavidM,  it's linked to the Italian immigrants who couldn't find an easy replacement for *schifo*, and often used it in their broken English: "Itza skiff/o"? In any case the Italian equivalent would be: "fare il bagno a mare, mi fa *proprio* schifo"

Comment: @Mari-Lou a funny scene I witnessed in a wine shop in Rome. An old man was hitting on the young Asian girl running the store. And he kept trying to get her to go out for dinner with her. He suggested they go for *vitello tonnato* and she replied, *"Mi fa schifo!"*. But, it was clear she wasn't talking about the *veal*.  ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider **[loathe](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/loathe)**

> to feel intense dislike, disgust, or hatred for; abhor; detest

If you need a noun, **loathing**.

Also

> - abominate
> - abhor
> - execrate

Comment: +1 for abhor.  I think that's actually the right word.  I have an abhorrence for swimming in natural water.

Answer (score 21):

I think the word you need is 'aversion'. It is less severe than phobia, but it is bad enough that professionals offer 'aversion therapy' treatment.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: I think aversion therapy adds aversion rather than getting rid of it.

Comment: @Oldcat Depends who's doing it. It is not as straightforward as book-keeping that's for sure.

Comment: Isn't it where you stop something you enjoy by tying it to something you don't.  Like "A Clockwork Orange" but without face paint and bowler hats.

Comment: This is the word I've used for years, but it still strikes me as not quite right.  I think that you may have found the answer for me, though.  When I looked up aversion, I found the word *abhor*.  I think this may be a better fit.

Answer (score 6):

> Swimming in fresh or seawater **[repulses](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/repulse)** me

would also fit

*Origin*

late Middle English: from Latin *repuls*- ‘driven back,’ from the verb *repellere* (see repel).

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion.  It is another word I've used for years, but didn't *quite* feel strong enough.

Comment: On the contrary, it describes very well the feeling of being creeped out by something; it's not a feeling of hate or fear, but describes something that physically makes you disgusted. You are repelled by seawater and fresh water. You could also say "tactile aversion", combining Ws2 and Susan's suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

On one end I think you have a **complex** or **hang-up**.  On the severe non-phobia side a **neurosis**.

Comment: Possibly, but again, no dysfunction. Just severe distaste.  Hang-up is the right track, but not severe enough.

Comment: @DavidM - loathe to me doesn't convey that you don't want be around something for at least a semi-irrational reason.  Loathe is what you use for a boss you don't like.  The things you mentioned are usually pleasant things to most people.  If I couldn't talk to girls with red-hair I would say I have a complex or hang-up.  I know that I should want to do it.  I don't loathe them.

Comment: I chose bib's answer due to suggesting abhor not loathe.  I said that in comments. I agree that loathe is not a good fit.

Comment: @DavidM - I don't know abhor is in the same boat with me.  I need something that signifies the irrational behavior.  I definitely have my complexes and I loathe having them.

Comment: Abhor is derived from the Latin *abhorrere* to shudder away from.  I think it is a perfect description of my issue with swimming in natural water.  Its not something I'm *afraid* to do, it's something I go out of my way to avoid due to extreme disgust.  I could say it skeeves me out, too.

Answer (score 3):

You could also say "swimming in natural water is **anathema** to me".

Or "I find swimming in natural water **repellent**."

Just coincidentally, I'm similar to you. I swim almost every day, but I much prefer pools to open water. I don't like the texture of sand at all. However, I like lakes or rivers for splashing around in, but only if they are really clean and clear.

The only problem is I'm not in love with chlorine, either. After years of exposure to it, it's having some pretty noticeable effects on the inside of my nose.

Answer (score 1):

"revulsion" came immediately to mind -- then i saw u had actually used it in your OP.
Still think it's best.  Verb "revulses".

btw, years ago, when i used to thoroughly follow bbc.co.uk science & health pages, i read of a correlation between pancreatic cancer and chlorine exposure, including pools.  Can't swim now without thinking of it.  Tried slathering myself with oil as protection -- only once, awful mess, perhaps because it was vegetable oil.  Didn't want to use mineral oil (UK "liquid paraffin") because petroleum products also risk-laden.  Furthermore, inhalation exposure remains.

Comment: Yeah. It's a good word, too. I was just trying to suss out if there was a better one.

Comment: Off-topic: Get a private pool with a salt-water treatment system.