# Are there suffixes akin to -phobe and -phile that are less extreme in meaning?

Tags: meaning, suffixes

The suffix *-phobia* means *fear of*, often *irrational fear of*.  For example, according to Wikipedia:

> [*Ophidiophobia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophidiophobia) or *ophiophobia* is a particular type of specific phobia,
>   the abnormal fear of snakes.

Is there a suffix attachable to *ophidio-* which would describe a person who is not afraid of snakes, except for, say, a coiled rattler encountered on a trail, but who dislikes them and would not willingly share space with one?

Similarly, an [*arachnophile*](http://www.digyourowngrave.com/arachnophiles-lovers-of-the-unlovable/) (**don't click here** if you are at all arachnophobic) is someone who loves spiders.  Is there a suffix for someone who likes spiders but does not love them?

These are Greek suffixes, and the Greeks, theoretically, were in favor of moderation.  So, are there suffixes in use in English, derivable from Greek or not, for *moderate like* and *moderate dislike*?

**Edit to explain why the question:  "Is there a suffix for loathing" does not answer my question**.  My question is NOT about fear and/or loathing.  My question is about moderate dislike (and moderate like).  I can watch a snake cross my driveway with interest, but would not want it in the house or lounging on my patio.   A person who loathed snakes would not be able to admire the smooth motion of the snake as it glided over the rough gravel and disappeared into the woods.  Loathe is very different from moderate dislike; Phobia is very different from caution.

Comment: As to your first question, see related threads, [_Is there a word that conveys an extreme distaste to the point nearing phobia?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155962), [_Word that means “tendency to avoid something”_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160318) and [_Is there a suffix for loathing?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58508)

Comment: @Kyle Thank you, but I asking about moderate like or moderate dislike, not love or loathing or fear.

Comment: Snake-averse. Snake-preferring.

Comment: Ophidio-tolerant; ophidio-intolerant.

Comment: If I were our marketing manager, *snake-friendly / -unfriendly* ; if I were my doctor, *snake-receptive / -resistant* ; if *The Economist*, *snake-inclined / -disinclined* ; if Buzzfeed, *snake-positive / snake-negative*. *Definitely plan on a visit to the Crocodile House if your date is snake-positive.* Of course, to the doctor, *snake-positive* is disturbing or intriguing on a whole other level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a suffix for loathing?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58508/is-there-a-suffix-for-loathing)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  I have edited the question to explain that my question is not about loathing or fear, but about moderate dislike (and moderate like).  A person who loathes snakes will react much more extremely, hysterically probably, to a snake crossing her driveway than will a person who has only a moderate dislike of snakes.  The second person will be interested in watching from a safe distance the smooth motion of the snake as it glides over rough gravel, and will be relieved to see it disappear into the woods.  continued

Comment: For not caring one whit about snakes, 'ophidio-meh'.

Comment: The person who loathes snakes will have a fit if a snake curls up on her patio and start screaming kill it, kill it!  The person with a moderate dislike of snakes will take a broom and sweep it into a sturdy paper bag and carry the bag into the woods to release it.   I am bemused as how anyone could think loathe = moderate dislike.

Comment: Then what's wrong with just saying "I don't like snakes"? Are you looking for a neutral meaning suffix? No. Are you looking for an extreme suffix? No. You're looking for a suffix which means dislike. There isn't one as far as I know. The accepted answer uses a modifier, mildly, that isn't a suffix. Ambivalent isn't a suffix either. Do you want me to reverse my close vote?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  YES.

Comment: You should probably close this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336197/is-there-an-established-suffix-like-phobia-that-expresses-dislike-but-not-fear) as being a duplicate of yours then.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  Done

Comment: related: [Is there a suffix like “phile” or “phobe” for don't care?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326890/is-there-a-suffix-like-phile-or-phobe-for-dont-care)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically accomplished using modifiers:

> John is mildly arachnophobic.

Aside from hyphenating existing words similar to those mentioned in the comments, there is no clear suffix for either meaning you requested.

Other relevant close-but-not-quite options:

- The prefixes `anti-` and `pro-`: "John is anti-snake."
- The suffix `-mania` which takes a very different twist: "John suffers from arachnomania." The exact meaning would be debatable but it could be played off of words such as "[pyromania](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=pyromania&allowed_in_frame=0)".
- The word `ambivalent` describes a "little of both" and conveys a sort of conflicted neutrality.

Comment: Ambivalent is exactly how I feel about snakes. ophidiobivalent is how I would describe myself in speech, if I were speaking rapidly; ophidio-ambivalent in writing.  I am more positive about spiders, although I do not love them.

Comment: @ab2 so in actual fact, you are indifferent toward snakes, you feel neither like nor dislike. Because a person who dislikes something will avoid situations where the object disliked is present. I live near the sea and I dislike seagulls, I will avoid visiting certain streets that are "infested" by them. I'm not scared of seagulls, I don't panic when I see one perched on the roof of my car, but I will never feed the beasts. So, I am "what" exactly?

Comment: @Mary Lou In the abstract, I am indifferent.  In reality, I will keep my distance.  I would not visit the reptile house at the zoo.  I would not drape a python around my neck, as is done in some fashion photos.  Ambivalent is so far the best word -- they have a place in the ecosystem, they are very old, they have as much right as I do to live, but let's each stay on our own turf.  As for fear, I would fear a grizzly bear if I encountered one hiking, and I would fear a rattler if I encountered one hiking.  I am on the negative side towards snakes, on the positive side towards spiders.