# Is there a suffix like "phile" or "phobe" for don't care?

Tags: suffixes

Thinking that every thing that you can like and dislike, you can also not care about and there may be a suffix for it.

Comment: Using "a-" or "an-" as a prefix (e.g., amoral, asexual) indicates an absence (of morals, sexuality, etc.) Perhaps something like that?

Comment: Amphiphile (from the Greek αμφις, amphis: both and φιλíα, philia: love, friendship) is a term describing a chemical compound possessing both hydrophilic (water-loving, polar) and lipophilic (fat-loving) properties. Maybe you can construct something with Amphi-, but it isn't a suffix.

Comment: Why are you searching for a suffix for which there are many prefixes for?

Comment: Many activists use the phobia to describe indifference or just mild dislike, because they think whoever is not strongly supporting their cause must be supporting the enemy. Of course, this doesn't mean we should adopt this (mis)usage of the word phobia.

Comment: @vsz you can find the quotes "Who is not with us is against us" and "Who is not against us is with us" in the Bible.

Comment: Apathy to the status quo is de facto support for it.

Comment: Is this question being asked by a *indifferentiaphille*, or is that not a word?

Comment: You could try -agnostic. It's used a bit in computing.

Comment: Would "-apathe" (~ no feeling) fit?

Comment: I'd suggest not trying.  As evidenced by the number of posts beginning "What's a word for ...", perhaps we try to pack too much into one word, sometimes with illogical results.  An arachnophobe *fears* spiders, but a homophobe probably doesn't fear homosexuals so much as hate them. And: fear/hate what?  Greek 'same-fear' by convention means *hatred* of people attracted to the same *sex*, but that's just a convention.  Perhaps we should be prepared to use phrases or sentences to express some ideas.

Comment: Marginally related:  What's the difference between ignorance and apathy?

Comment: I would guess apathetic or agnostic. But apathetic is more focused on emotional don't care and agnostic more of a rational don't care.

@Nij apathy derived from or caused by status quo is not, however.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

As far as I know, no.  We could make one up, here.  "-phile" and "-phobe" are derived from the greek words "philia" (love) and "phobos" (fear), so we'd want to look for an greek word meaning "indifference", I think.

"***adiaphoria***" looks like an early contender, being what Google translate comes back with for "**indifference**".  There is already a philosophical concept "adiaphora" (note no 'i' at the end) meaning "indifferent things", referring to (my summary) things which are **neither moral nor immoral**.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiaphora

This isn't quite what we're after, and it's a bit long, anyway - it would be nice to be able to have a single-syllable suffix like "phile" or "phobe".

"**neutral**" gives "***oudéteros***", which again is a bit long.

Perhaps we could use "***mesis***" which means "**middle**" - so you could have the adjective suffix "***-mesic***" like "phobic", and the noun suffix "***-meso***" like "phobe".

Eg, an "audiomeso" is someone who neither hates nor loves music, and if you genuinely didn't give a sh*t about whether someone is gay, you could call yourself "homomesic".

EDIT:  @Nathaniel, in the comments, pointed out that the noun form suffix should be "-mese", not "-meso", so "audiomese" or "homomese".  This feels right to me and I thank him for it.

Comment: Done deal. This is now officially part of English. Thank you.

Comment: I'll wait till it's in the dictionary before I order my "Neologist" badge :)

Comment: I think I prefer the sound of *audiomesiac*.

Comment: @Lynn good idea, but on second thought, `audiomesiac` would be the noun, and `audiomesic` would be the adjective. They are spelled and pronounced too similarly to each other. `Audiomeso` is sufficient different.

Comment: "meso" does not work as a noun suffix. we don't use "phobo" or "philo" as suffixes, only as prefixes.

Comment: @sumelic by analogy to those two examples (phobo -> phobe; philo -> phile), the suffix should be *mese*, as in "audiomese".

Comment: LOL. 1+ for "genuinely not giving a shit if someone is gay".

Comment: *audiomese* definitely sounds English to me (while *audiomesiac* sounds... *forced*, somehow). Then again, what do I know, English is not my first language  and we bl**dy foreigners don't understand anything about anything, anyway...

Comment: I think 'phile' and 'phobe' are only monosyllabic in english.

Comment: @Nathaniel I agree with "audiomese".

Comment: Keep a link to this post, it's going to help the etymologists of the future.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't "homomese" and "heteromese" technically mean the same thing? In this case, "-mese" is more a component of a blend than a functional suffix, like in "homophobic". I personally tend to dislike these words, because albeit they are formed in analogy to other popular blends, they don't reflect the true meaning of "homo" and "hetero", which then kind of shifts, disregarding the roots of these words (also "trans" and "cis").

Comment: @IllidanS4 you're right, it's a sort of "evolution" which, at the end, leaves you with something that doesn't make sense in the original context.  I think that might be a feature of organic language development, as opposed to something more "regulated".

Comment: I guess I can live with this. That makes me _mesomesic_, right?

Comment: @IllidanS4 what this made me realise is that the word "homophobic" is actually a really bad word for "afraid of/hating gay people", as it translates as "afraid of same-ness", whereas it's used meaning is kind of the opposite: being afraid of people whose sexuality is different to yours.

Comment: @IllidanS4 No; one could be indifferent about heteros while loving/hating homos, or vice versa. I also like *-mese* because it sounds like *Chinese* which is also neutral in opinion about China.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman you don't think there are any people who really like gay people, and are indifferent about "straight" people?  I'd have thought there must be lots of people with that sort of prejudice.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Hence ", or vice versa".

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Sorry, I misread your comment:  When you said "No; one could ..." I read it as "No-one could..."

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Though the original definition of "homomese" should be not caring about someone being gay, then "heteromese" not caring about someone being straight, doesn't it simply mean not caring about one's sexuality, thus the same thing? "-mese" doesn't reflect loving/hating, but simply indifference, which seems equivalent when appended to both poles (homo-/hetero-) of a quality (sexuality).

Comment: @IllidanS4 yes I think that's right.

Comment: There's also bisexuality, zoosexuality, etc., and Christmese, Islamese, and ipsumese are also relevant.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Good point, I forgot bisexuality (and asexuality), which together make up 4 poles of some quality which Wikipedia calls "sexual orientation continuum", simply sexual attraction. This makes my original statement weaker, as it now raises a question whether one can be for example purely"bimese"(not caring if one is bisexual)but not "homomese",hence caring about one's sexuality only if it's homosexual, but not if it's bisexual.I guess it is possible,so it depends on your understanding of the word's meaning (e.g.not caring about sexual attraction/sexuality in general or just one pole

Comment: Not caring about sexual attraction/sexuality in general = asexual.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman But "asexual" is already used for a person who doesn't feel any sexual attraction at all. Using our suffix, it could se something along "sexomese".

Comment: A second meaning for "adiaphorous" is "indifferent or neutral," according to the 1913 Webster's.

Comment: "audiomeso"....."homomese".... xdddd

Answer (score 190):

I am not aware of a suffix *per se* with that meaning, but I sometimes see the idea expressed by forming a pairing with the word ***agnostic***.  Although the first meaning of this word is specifically about religious belief, it can also be used in a more general sense:

> 2. a person who is unwilling to commit to an opinion about something

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agnostic))

Though M-W does not document it, other sources indicate that [the word can also be used as an adjective](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/agnostic) to describe a person who holds the (non-)beliefs of an agnostic on a particular subject.

Thus, you might say "Chrome and Internet Explorer both have strong partisans, but I am browser-***agnostic***."

Comment: I think this is better than mine, although it's more fun to try to invent your own word :)

Comment: Good idea but I like the invented suffix more. Thanks.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, of course inventing is more fun, but here on Stack Exchange, [we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) :-).  On a more serious note, if the objective is to communicate the idea effectively then inventing a new suffix by drawing on Greek is unlikely to be a good approach.

Comment: To my ear (and based on the etymology), agnostic refers more to lack of knowledge rather than lack of concern. An agnostic may vehemently insist that he cannot know whether or not God exists, but it might still be the very focus of his life.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker The answer is correct. While, in the context of religious beliefs, the word means what you say, "x-agnostic" is a perfectly idiomatic way to say "doesn't care about x" or "isn't affected by x." I can speak from personal experience in saying that this usage is especially common in software design where we say "y is x-agnostic" to mean that x has been sufficiently abstracted that y doesn't have to know or care which exact implementation of x is in use. For example, a DirectX  program can be agnostic of which video card is present, as long as it's one that support DirectX.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker When I saw the question title, "x-agnostic" and "x-neutral" were going to be my suggestions... then I saw that they were the two existing answers. :)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, I'm aware of the etymology, but the example sentence I provided is of a form that I sometimes hear, and that sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: Yeah, I commonly use the "x-agnostic" terminology, and it's always readily understood and unambiguous (to the extent that intentional ambiguity can be unambiguous).

Comment: @MaxWilliams, we at StackExchange do not have a sense of humour we are aware of.

Answer (score 89):

I propose '-meh'

- Arachnophobe
- Arachnophile
- Arachnomeh

In the right tone of voice, I think that could work.

Meh, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meh)

> Meh is an interjection used as an expression of indifference or
>   boredom. It may also mean "be it as it may". It is often regarded
>   as a verbal shrug of the shoulders

Comment: This is good, I still prefer the Greek-derived version, though.

Comment: Admitting neologisms, that would be OK for me : simple and efficient. Though, building words upon "roots" is quite efficient for anybody trying to understand an unknown word.

Comment: This also would not require the extended explanations to our wordomeh friends.

Comment: Arachno-meh and arachnomese are a bit similar, I guess the true answer lies somewhere in between.

Comment: @Alexander "Arachno-mehs"? As a bonus it could be a homonym depending on how you pronounce it.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester I nominate that these answers be joined! Arachnomese is the official spelling... but the hip kids would all know to say it "arachnomehs"

Comment: @Alexander I'm a bit suffixomese about the choice ...

Answer (score 36):

It seems you are looking for a concise, easily understandable term for someone who is neither a `-phile` nor a `-phobe`. I would suggest the suffix `-neutral`. It may be more of an adjective than a noun, but it can be pressed into service as a noun by ellipsis. Thus:

> Which of the following describes you best?
>
> **I am a technophile**
>
> **I am a technophobe**
>
> **I am techno-neutral**
>
> 90% of the technophiles, 50% of the techno-neutrals* and 10% of the technophobes said they had heard of the product.

(* where `techno-neutrals` is an ellipsis for `techno-neutral respondents` to the survey.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think using a Greek-derived suffix is more stylistically appropriate, by maintaining consistency with "phobe" and "phile". Also, using "neutral" requires a dash, whereas taking a foreign word and turning it into a new suffix doesn't.

Comment: *I am technomesic* or *I am a technomese* definitely sounds way geeky and very, very high-brow — definitely much cooler than *I am techno-neutral*, that's for sure! :-)

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn It suffers from not being immediately understandable, however, which makes it rather poseurish.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of and seems superior to the other answers. @Mr.TA you asked whether there _was_ a suffix. This _is_ a suffix. and it _did_ already exist. You didn't ask someone to make you a new one out of thin air, future tense, with a totally arbitrary etymological basis. What's wrong with hyphens, anyway?

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn Sounding geeky and high-brow are not a measure of utility, if that's what you mean. Real-world efficacy goes right down. People won't know what you're on about. You'd just be forming a dialect based on opacity and elitism, not likely to achieve anything that's practically useful.

Comment: @underscore_d hyphenated words are not suffixes. Words come into being all the time. "Phobe" was also once a "high-browed geeky aristocrat" way of saying "hater". Instead of "claustrophobe", we can say "claustro-hater", or perhaps, "elevator-hater". Should we drop the "phobe" from the language?

Answer (score 18):

If an english suffix would fit, I would suggest **-indifferent** as in:

- techno-indifferent,
- arachno-indifferent,
- agora-indifferent,
- homo-indifferent…

Answer (score 6):

Not the best choice suggested here, but one might use `-**ambivalent**`:

> ▸adjective: feeling two different things about someone or something at the same time, for example that you like them and dislike them
>
> ▸ adjective:  uncertain or unable to decide about what course to
>   follow ("Was ambivalent about having children")
>
> ▸ adjective:  characterized by a mixture of opposite feelings or
>   attitudes ("She felt ambivalent about his proposal")

Example usage:

- "I'm cinephilic, Sinophobic, and cyno-ambivalent"

Comment: Ambivalent is a good alternative to phobe and phile, and it would be a meaningful and recognizable suffix. Though it doesn't mean you don't care.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Indeed. Although it may have picked up some of that meaning today.

Answer (score 4):

## -apathic

A slightly lighter-weight version of @EricKigathi's [-apathetic](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/328068/18673).

> **-pathic**, suffix meaning *affected by* —[The Free Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/-pathic) (citing Mosby's Medical Dictionary, 2009(
>
> **apathic**, without sensation or feeling. —[The Free Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/apathic) (citing Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary, 2007)
>
> **apathic**, synonym of apathetic —[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apathic)

Despite the frequent concurrence of *don't know* and *don't care*, they mean different things.  @PellMel's [browser-agnostic](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/326900/18673) is a good term for code that doesn't **know** what browser it's running on (and doesn't need to know, because it's compatible with all of them). But the OP question contrasts -phobe and -phile so this is about feeling. Browser-apathic code was written by someone who didn't **care** which browser they were trying it on (so it may only work on one of them).

Technology:

- techno-phobic - hates technology, averse to using it
- techno-philic - loves technology, early adopter of gadgets
- techno-agnostic - ignorant of technology, doesn't know how to use it
- techno-apathic - apathetic about technology, as likely to choose a nontechnical solution

Spiders:

- arachno-philic - fascinated by spiders
- arachno-phobic - afraid of spiders
- arachno-agnostic - ignorant about spiders, but might want to learn
- arachno-apathic - apathetic about spiders, neither jumps at them nor checks which species

@MaxWilliams' [-mesic](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/326897/18673) may be useful if you wanted a term that was ambiguous about knowing or caring. Is there a case where that's better than being specific? Haven't thought of one yet.

I'm doubtful there exists one clear middle ground between love and hate. @SAH's [-ambivalent](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/328074/18673) is a third. Maybe there are others, and they shouldn't be muddled.

@user1892306's [-meh](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/327117/18673) is exquisitely precise in meaning but it doesn't look like a suffix; turning it into one loses recognition even from those familiar with this neologism.

Comment: I think your “-agnostic” definitions are a bit off.  “Agnostic” really does mean indifferent, not ignorant, resistant, or indecisive.  An example: One term that's used to describe oneself by software developers is “language-agnostic”, which means that they don't play favorites with any given programming language; instead they focus on how to build things with the underlying CS concepts and just use the language that is best for the specific problem, or best matches what a company's already using.

Comment: Ambivalent means having two opinions at the same time, e.g. unsure which is correct. Arachno-ambivalent, not sure whether you like them or hate them - on the on hand they catch flies, on the other....

Answer (score 3):

I'd also propose `-apathetic`

> Apathetic (adj): Showing or feeling no interest, enthusiasm, or concern

**Apathy** derives from French `apathie`, via Latin from Greek `apatheia`, from `apathēs` **without feeling,** from `a-` **without** + `pathos` **suffering.**

Example usage:

- `Ailurophilic` Loves Cats
- `Ailuroapathetic` Is unconcerned about or
  indifferent to cats

Comment: Good job, this is the word I was wracking my brain for.

Comment: Why not **apath** then as the opposite of **path** as in *psychopath*?

Comment: @danielAzuelos like [my answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/328118/18673)? :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is not worth it using a short suffix that is semantically only close to what you are trying to express, for a concept used that rarely.

You could invent a new suffix that describes by definition exactly what you want to say, otherwise the usage of extra syllables should be preferred over losing part of the meaning.

Indifference is oftentimes used as the default condition, a placeholder, and it isn't univocal, as opposed to like and dislike.

When you are indifferent it can mean that you haven't thought of the matter before, and thus you haven't made up your mind yet [**Case 1**]. Or it can mean that you have thought of it and you really are indifferent [**Case 2**].

This ambiguity increases the complexity of inventing such a suffix.

To illustrate the above, let's suppose that there exist arachnids, and people can either be averse or fond of them. What a person feels towards arachnids can be thought of as a variable that can have one of the following values: 'like', 'dislike', 'indifferent', which describe fondness, aversion or indifference towards arachnids. The *value* indifference is the indifference we described in Case 2. The variable however can also have **no value** (this is exactly how 0 works in numbers -it's a placeholder). This "no value" is the indifference described in Case 1.

In programming we do:

```
if the value of arachnid_variable is 'like'
    Then the_person likes arachnids
else if the value of arachnid_variable is 'dislike'
    Then the_person dislikes arachnids
else if the value of arachnid_variable is 'indifferent'
    Then the_person gives 0 fucks about arachnids
else
    the_person is indifferent towards arachnids because he is not even aware of their existence, or because he has never thought to form an opinion about them
```

A suffix like -phile or -phobe for indifference would have purpose only in Case 2, when you want to make the statement that you have considered the 'like' and 'dislike' options, and you have opted for indifference. In contexts where indifference is the default condition (i.e. the "no value" we described above), it should not be stated, and thus such a suffix would be unusable.

As it's very well stated in the accepted answer (by Max Williams), adiaphoria (= indifference) is indeed the concept between -phile and -phobe (even though it is said that the opposite of love is indifference and not hate ^^).

In Greek, adiaphoria eventually boils down to "the act of making no distinction/ differentiation" (probably pretty close to 'indifference'). So, if you want to invent a new suffix derived from greek "*-mesis*" and "*-oudeteros*" (concepts of *in the middle* and *neutral*) are not correct. "*-adiaphoric*" could work ("adiaphoro" with the Greek suffix), but I would prefer the English suffix -indifferent, as proposed by daniel Azuelos, which is simple and precise.

Answer (score 0):

The suffix "-path" (as in apathy) may have this meaning, but I can't think of any other examples right now besides "sociopath" (one who doesn't care about society), and possibly also "psychopath". Clearly, the suffix can also have other meanings, as in "homoeopath" and "naturopath", but in some cases, I think it may have the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: According to Michael Quinion, _Ologies and Isms: Word Beginnings and Endings_ (2002), -path typically refers to a practitioner (of some treatment) or to a sufferer (of a condition). The -pathy in words like _apathy_ and _sympathy_ comes from the Greek word for "feeling" and the a- in _apathy_ is the alpha privative (or negative), as in "not feeling."

Answer (score -6):

"*Don't care*" means one has no heart for something, it is not usually synonymous with "*unfamiliar*" or "innocent".  It connotes veiled disdain for a given topic, making *-nostic* & *-neutral* & *-middle* (Gr. *-meso*) too gentle, and *-phobic* insincere.

The prefix "**anti-**" seems more correct than any available suffix.  The most appropriate term in Greek: ["*ekhthros*"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=enemy), (personal enemy), is unsuitable for an English suffix.  ("Techno-ekthros?")

There's also '*-clast*' (Gr. *-klastes*, a breaker or wrecker), the sole English word being *iconoclast*, used to describe certain Christian zealots that vandalized or defaced sculpture and art which they believed promoted idolatry and false gods; later *iconoclast* mellows and signifies nonconformists and radicals who break with tradition, yet need not break physical objects.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question. There's a big difference between "not caring for something", and "not caring either way."

Comment: @LevelRiverSt, I'd grant a small difference, but only that much -- "not care", "don't care", etc., _care_ is a strong word, negating it is forceful too.  If not for that strength, these should be virtually equivalent:      1) 'I'm OK either way'       2) 'I don't mind either way'     3) 'I don't care either way'.

Comment: @agc I strongly disagree that the result of negating a strong word is also strong.

Negating the above: `I do not strongly disagree that ...`
I thing this goes to show my point.

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne, that point is quite correct, but it seems to be based on an *in*correct presumption that a generality had been asserted.  _Don't care_  is merely a peculiar instance of strong negation.  More instances: _warmthless_,  _heartless_, _loveless_, _soulless_, etc.

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne Indeed. Compare `Have to / Don´t have to` vs `Must / Mustn't`