# Is there a prefix to denote neutrality?

Tags: etymology, prefixes, negative-prefixes

English has prefixes to denote opposition as well as absence.

For example:

- 'gnostic' vs 'agnostic' (having knowledge vs absence of knowledge)
- 'social' vs 'asocial' vs 'anti social' (being social, not being social, being against society)

However there is a subtle difference between the absence of something and being neutral towards it. For example let;s say that I want to indicate that I am a little bit social, but not too social.

I am not 'asocial' because it's false that I am not social. But I am also not fully social. Rather I am something in the middle.

The above is just an example, it doesn't have to be the word 'social' I just want to know whether English has a prefix to explicitly convey the subtility of neutrality.

Comment: For any contrast (including 'un-', 'ab-', etc.) that establishes a gradation between poles, there may be a zero point in the middle, or two separate zeroes at each opposing end, so prefixes like 'sub-' or 'semi-' will be ambiguous.  The best way to express the subtlety of neutrality is simply to not mention the quality at all.

Comment: The difficulty here is the way you've worded your premise, as "something in the middle" doesn't necessarily equate to "neutral". The former would be covered by *semi-*, but I suspect neutrality is too nuanced and context-dependent to have given rise to a specific prefix.

Comment: Not everything can be expressed well in one word. Here's a related question with, in my opinion, fairly unsatisfactory answers: [Is there a suffix like “phile” or “phobe” for don't care?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326890)

Comment: [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/neutral_3) gives _-neutral_ as a suffix and _gender-neutral_ as an example. However, it can be considered a compound noun also. [This might not be exactly what you ask for]

Comment: There are lots of prefixes that might do in some context, but there's no general prefix. For instance "hypo-" meaning less than normal (often in science or medicine); "semi-" as mentioned or the similar "demi-" (e.g. "demisexual"); "para-" which means near, apart from, or resembling amongst other meanings (e.g. "paralegal"); "pseudo-" which can mean false but can also mean resembling or like; or in some cases even "de-", "dis-", or "un-".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with ***quasi-***

M-W.com

> [resembling in some degree](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quasi)

Lexico

> [1.1Being partly or almost.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/quasi-)

This is demonstrated well by your own example of *social*

quasi-social

> [(Of an activity or relationship) having some but not all of the
> features that would identify it as genuinely social; having a social
> aspect but with some other purpose or motivation; Zoology (especially
> with reference to insects and spiders) exhibiting some of the
> characteristics of social organization, especially cooperative brood
> care.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/quasi-social)

This would work for many examples (quasi-literate, quasi-real, quasi-federalist), but it wouldn't work so well with *gnostic* because capital-G *Gnostic* has such a specific meaning. Quasi-Gnostic has the meaning, resembling or having some parts of Gnosticism. But I'm not sure there is a need to need to distinguish between the literal meaning of *gnostic* and *agnostic* in any event. These usages are uncommon and likely to be confused if you try to find a middle ground. Either you have knowledge, or you do not. In real world usages, *agnostic* is already a midway point between *theist* and *atheist.*

Answer (score 1):

Prefixes that denote the concept of **“both”** — rather than *neutrality* — are sometimes used in situations similar to that in the poster’s example. In addition to “bi-” (which is more strongly associated with the number *two*) these include:

> [**amphi-**](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=amphi&title=21st)

*Greek, meaning 'both' or 'on both sides'.* Chambers

> [**ambi-**](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=ambi&title=21st)

*Latin, from ambo both.* Chambers

The are relatively few examples, many of which are technical or scientific. Examples are

- *amphibious* (able to operate both on water and on land)
- *amphiphilic* (of molecule etc. having both hydrophibic and hydrophilic components)
- *amphimixis* (fusion of male and female gametes)

and

- *ambidextrous* (able to use both hands equally)
- *ambilateral* (relating to both sides)
- *ambivalent* (one person having opposing attitudes towards something)

As a pedantic traditionalist, I am not an advocate of inventing words, but it struck me that **ambisocial** had a plausible ring to it. So plausible, it turns out, that it appears in something that goes under the name of [*Urban Dictionary*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ambisocial). The choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

English has lots of [negative prefixes and other negative words](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) that color the grammar and meaning in strange ways. This does not mean that it has prefixes for "opposition", or "absence", let alone "positive", or "neutral". It doesn't; negation is enough to do the job.

Comment: With 'a little bit social', OP seems to want a prefix indicating 'about 10%'.

Comment: I don't know anything like that, @Edwin, do you? Why do people think there's one magic word (or prefix, even!) for every teeny little variation they can think of? Has anybody ever heard of phrases?

Comment: Moving on quickly (before somebody invents one).

Answer (score -2):

I Think Your Looking For Neutro.

Comment: This would benefit from a reference.  Please see the [tour] and [FAQ].  You are encouraged to [edit] your answer.