# Which verb describes the most hate for something/someone?

Tags: verbs

I'm curious to know which word describes the most (maximum or most extreme) hate for something. For example let's say I really hate the educational system or american politics.

I can say:

- I **hate** the educational system.
- I **detest** the educational system.
- I **loathe** the educational system.

So, which verb describes the most hate for something?

Comment: I'd go with *abhor* or *loathe*

Comment: I feel "hate" is a somewhat weaker word than the others since it is more common, so it gets used by way of exaggeration for things that people don't actually hate that much.

Comment: @sumelice: true

Comment: George, you may want to edit your question so that it stays open for a while. The way it is now, it is primarily about opinion. This is also very similar to another [question that has already been answered](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155962/is-there-a-word-that-conveys-an-extreme-distaste-to-the-point-nearing-phobia/155965#155965)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're asking is subjective. There is no definitive ranking on one verb versus another. It's going go to be up to the reader and how they interpret it.

That being said, I would agree that going with a verb that was less common, or less used, will have a greater impact. Such as "abhor" or "loathe".